# Residual plot for panel data question

Tags: regression, data-visualization, residuals, goodness-of-fit

Currently, I am doing a panel data analysis to predict/forecast the housing prices, and I want to use a residual plot to detect if my model is ok or not. I have been reading many articles showing how to use residual plot to detect problems of model, but i still cannot tell what this plot is speaking about.

My dependent variable is housing sold prices in the 50 states of the U.S. in 3 different time periods (1980, 1990 & 2000) with total 150 obs, and the independent variables are economic factors such as income, sales tax; race factors such as Asian, Black, Hispanic; geographic factors such as north east, west, mid west, south east; social factors such as crimes; and so forth (not about the house characteristics like bedrooms).

The residual plot is based on the TSLS model with fixed effects using R. 
The R-squared is 0.44856, adjusted R-squared is 0.10691.

[image: residual plot]

Can anyone please tell me is there a problem with my model based on the plot above?

Comment: @FransRodenburg Hi, thank you for pointing out. I have edited it, thank you so much!